# IONIC 3 Google Maps Native plugin background color white

Tags: ionic-framework, maps, native

I'm using the IONIC Google Maps native plugin and followed this tutorial:

https://www.javascripttuts.com/implementing-native-google-maps-in-an-ionic-application/

So it works, but, I have a white background color. According to the tutorial there is a css fix :

```
ion-app .nav-decor{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

But this doesn't work. Does anybody have this same issue?

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the background color, you need to use `Environment.setBackgroundColor("red");`
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.0.0/class/Environment/setBackgroundColor/README.md